# How can i get list of postgresql database through php or using just sql query?

Tags: php, postgresql-9.3

What i want to do is to make a drop down list of all the databases of my postgresql 9.3  server using php .
if i can get just the sql script that can do the trick then i can handle the php part.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information is stored in [`pg_database`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-database.html):

```
select datname
from pg_database;
```

Obviously you need to connect some database in order to be able to run the query.

Comment: for other users i have added some more in next answer. thanks .:)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT pg_database.datname as "Database",
       pg_user.usename as "postgres" FROM pg_database, pg_user
WHERE pg_database.datdba = pg_user.usesysid
UNION
SELECT pg_database.datname as "Database",
       NULL as "postgres" FROM pg_database
WHERE pg_database.datdba NOT IN (SELECT usesysid FROM pg_user)
ORDER BY "Database"  -- database that belong to user postgres

SELECT pg_database.datname as "Database" FROM pg_database; -- all databases 

SELECT datname FROM pg_database
WHERE datistemplate = false;
```